# Running a single test works, but running multiple tests fails - Flask and Pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

This is really strange. I have the following simple flask application:

```
- root
- myapp
  - a route with /subscription_endpoint
- tests
  - test_az.py
  - test_bz.py
```

test_az.py and test_bz.py look both the same. There is a setup (taken from https://diegoquintanav.github.io/flask-contexts.html) and then one simple test:

```
import pytest
from myapp import create_app
import json

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def app(request):
    from myapp import create_app
    return create_app('testing')


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def app_context(app):
    """Creates a flask app context"""
    with app.app_context():
        yield app

@pytest.fixture
def client(app_context):
    return app_context.test_client(use_cookies=True)


def test_it(client):
    sample_payload = {"test": "test"}
    response = client.post("/subscription_endpoint", json=sample_payload)
    assert response.status_code == 500
```

running pytest, will run both files, but test_az.py will succeed, while test_bz.py will fail. The http request will return a 404 error, meaning test_bz cannot find the route in the app.
If I run them individually, then they booth succeed. This is very strange! It seems like the first test is somehow influencing the second test.

I have added actually a third test test_cz.py, which will fail as well. So only the first one will ever run. I feel like this has something todo with those fixtures, but no idea where to look.

Comment: Could you provide the test that fails and the one succeeds?

Comment: well... they are both exactely the same! test_az.py and test_bz.py contains the exactely same content

Comment: ok, then why you don't create a `conftest.py` for fixtures e.g. for client fixture and use the same fixture in both tests? Now if you're saying that the provided code is the example of a test that is the same in another file, then you are creating 2 fixtures for a client. I would first clean it up and create a 1 `conftest.py` that contains all the fixtures and then use them in your tests this might help you. Try to use `pytest` as described in flask documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/. Did it changes anything to your tests?

Comment: thanks a lot. That was it. I added conftest.py and put relooked at the fixtures again. ... now it's working perfectly fine

Comment: I have added this as answer and if your happy just accept as the answer so others would see that it's resolved :) thanks! and good luck on your coding journey sir!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a `conftest.py` for fixtures e.g. for client fixture and use the same fixture in both tests?

Now if you're saying that the provided code is the example of a test that is the same in another file, then you are creating 2 fixtures for a client. I would first clean it up and create a 1 `conftest.py` that contains all the fixtures and then use them in your tests this might help you.

Check out also how to use `pytest` as described in Flask documentation

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I have a conftest.py, still only the very first test ran works and the rest fail.